# What is the mainstream economic response/interpretation of double burden, or the problem with unwaged reproductive labor?

Tags: macroeconomics, labor-economics

I have recently done some readings into unwaged reproductive labor (the labor done in the household, primarily by women, which facilitates the household), and the arguments provided support the idea that household work is not purely an act of goodwill, but rather a form of labor. I find these arguments compelling, but I did not find any treatments of the subject in economic papers—barring one paper where reproductive labor was included in a participatory economic system.

Papers referenced:

Wages Against Housework - Federici 1975
Migrant Filipina Domestic Workers and the International Division of Reproductive Labor - Parrenas 2000

Comment: Hi! Can you please explain what you mean by "treatment of the subject" or what "the problem" is? I think most economists do not question that household work is work/labor.

Comment: Ah! So sorry, I suppose the question would be why this form of unpaid labor exists within the economy, or what utility these people are deriving from their labor (as opposed to forms of labor with no remuneration that we have deemed unacceptable like slavery, or labor in internment camp). How is this labor accounted for in a traditional analysis of the economy?